# React: mapping through a list of svg images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to map through a list of svg images and show enough description corresponding to the svg image.

index.js

```
import {ReactComponent as Pic1} from "../../../../assets/buyer-1.svg";
import {ReactComponent as Pic2} from "../../../../assets/buyer-2.svg";
import {ReactComponent as Pic3} from "../../../../assets/buyer-3.svg";


const data = [
  {
    id: `1`,
    title: "Coming soon",
    description:'',
    img: Pic1,
  },
  {
    id: `2`,
    title: "Coming soon",
    description:'',
    img: Pic2,
  },
  {
    id: `3`,
    tile: "Coming soon",
    description:'',
    img: Pic3,
  },
]

function Test() {
  return (
{data.map(({ id, title,description, img }) => (
                  <div key={id} className="guest--item swiper-slide">
                    <div>
                    <img key={id} src={img} alt='mySvgImage' />
                      <h1>{title}</h1>
                      <h2>{description}</h2>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
)}
```

currently when i check my react website i can only see mySvgImage which is the alt 3 times and cant see the actual image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `SVG's` as `React Component` hence you should use them as Component itself.

In you code you are passing a `React Component` (SVG's which you imported as React Component) as a `src` attribute to an `<img>` tag which is invalid.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {ReactComponent as Pic1} from "../../../../assets/buyer-1.svg";
import {ReactComponent as Pic2} from "../../../../assets/buyer-2.svg";
import {ReactComponent as Pic3} from "../../../../assets/buyer-3.svg";

const data = [
  {
    id: `1`,
    title: "Coming soon",
    description: "",
    Image: Pic1
  },
  {
    id: `2`,
    title: "Coming soon",
    description: "",
    Image: Pic2
  },
  {
    id: `3`,
    tile: "Coming soon",
    description: "",
    Image: Pic3
  }
];

function Test() {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(({ id, title, description, Image }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <div>
            <Image />  {/* Use Image as Component */}
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <h2>{description}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are importing your images the wrong way. I have made this working CodeSandbox which is exactly the same as your example. Check how I imported images and it's working just fine. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/img-import-nwqnt5)

Answer (score 0):

Where you got it wrong is importing **SVG** as React Component and using for a **src** attribute in an **img** tag.
So u don't need to import as ReactComponent.

You can import this way.

```
import Pic1 from "../../../../assets/buyer-1.svg";
```

```js
import Pic1 from "../../../../assets/buyer-1.svg";
import Pic2 from "../../../../assets/buyer-2.svg";
import Pic3 from "../../../../assets/buyer-3.svg";


const data = [
  {
    id: `1`,
    title: "Coming soon",
    description:'',
    img: Pic1,
  },
  {
    id: `2`,
    title: "Coming soon",
    description:'',
    img: Pic2,
  },
  {
    id: `3`,
    tile: "Coming soon",
    description:'',
    img: Pic3,
  },
]

function Test() {
  return (
{data.map(({ id, title,description, img }) => (
   <div key={id} className="guest--item swiper-slide">
     <div>
       <img key={id} src={img} alt='mySvgImage' />
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <h2>{description}</h2>
     </div>
   </div>
  ))}
)}
```