# Map an object of svg in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have this png's images:

`import { alergology, cardiology, dermatology, endocrinology, gynecology } from '@/constants/images'`

Made this object:

```
const images: IObjectKeys = {
  Alergología: alergology,
  Cardiología: cardiology,
  Dermatología: dermatology,
  Endocrinología: endocrinology,
  Ginecología: gynecology,
};
```

And render like this :

```
export const addingImgToSpecialties = (specialties: Speciality[]) =>
  specialties.map((specialty) => {
    const { name } = specialty;
    return {
      ...specialty,
      img: images[name],
    };
  });
```

Now I need to to change pngs to svgs , this is what I am trying to do 1)Import the svg 2)Then add it to value.

Already installed react-native-svg and used it in other views without mapping.

`import Alergology from '@assets/images/specialties/alergologia.svg';`

```
const images: IObjectKeys = {
  Alergología: Alergology,
  Cardiología: Cardiology,
  Dermatología: Dermatology,
  Endocrinología: Dndocrinology,
  Ginecología: Dynecology,
};
```

but in this case, it crashes the application, I get this error

`[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.]`

How I should do this ?

Comment: Image component cannot render svg files , react-native-svg will be required , kindly check this link https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md#use-with-svg-files

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already installed react-native-svg.

Comment: this answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/71368386/10127727